# $240x^2y^3 - 180x^3y^4$ - Factor the given.

Tags: factoring

$240x^2y^3 - 180x^3y^4$

Question: Please Factor the Given Expression.

Thanks.

In factoring... Is it similar to the Factor Tree? Instead do we not use the tree?

My Answer (attempt $1$)

$15xy^2 (16xy-12x^2y^2)$
Is this correct? Or rather, is this a possible answer?

Comment: Please, show us your attempt.

Comment: This is completely trivial. Where do you have problems?

Comment: Consider removing the shared highest powers of $x$ and $y$ from each term, then consider common factors for the coefficients.

Comment: Charmander, in what context was the question asked?

Comment: what is the gcd of $240$ and $180$?

Comment: Yes, it is a possible answer, but you can still take out a common factor of $4xy$.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$15xy^2\cdot(16xy-12x^2y^2)$ is indeed a possible answer.

But the terms "$16xy$" and "$12x^2y^2$" still have a common factor of $4xy$.

In other words: $16xy-12x^2y^2=4xy\cdot(4-3xy)$.

Hence: $15xy^2\cdot(16xy-12x^2y^2)=15xy^2\cdot4xy\cdot(4-3xy)=60x^2y^3\cdot(4-3xy)$.

Comment: Nice. I got it! The solution! Thanks!!

Comment: @Charmander: You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer if you consider it to be the most appropriate one here (by clicking on the V next to it).

Answer (score 1):

$$
240x^2y^3 - 180x^3y^4
=60x^2y^3(4-3xy)
$$